# Asp.net Core MVC - on form posting to controller IEnumerable model in controller action is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a problem  when I am trying to post IEnumerable from razor view to Controllor action method. Also result is the same if I use List. 
I post my controllor action method also in comment. In my controllor action method I got list that is empty.

This is my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Subject>
<form asp-action="AddNewSubjects" asp-controller="Teacher" method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Number of class</th>
                <th>Level</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model != null)
            {

    var item = Model.ToList();
    @for(int i=0;i<Model.Count();i++)
                {
            <tr>
                <td>@item[i].ID</td>
                <td>@item[i].Name</td>
                <td>@item[i].ClassNumber</td>
                <td>@item[i].Level</td>

            </tr>

                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-5">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save all subjects" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my Controller:

```
            private readonly ISubjectService _subjectService;

            public TeacherController(ISubjectService subjectService)
            {
                _subjectService= subjectService;
            }

     [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult AddNewSubjects(IEnumerable<Subject> subjects)
            {
                var newSubjects= (from p in subjects
                                    where p.State== Status.New
                                    select p);
                    var result = _subjectService.SaveTeacherSubjects(newSubjects);
                return View("ProfesorPages");   
            }
```

Comment: This is my controllor method:
[HttpPost]
                public IActionResult AddNewSubjects(IEnumerable<Subject> subjects)
                {
                    var newSubjects= (from p in subjects
                                        where p.State== Status.New
                                        select p);
                        var result = _subjectService.SaveTeacherSubjects(newSubjects);
                    return View("ProfesorPages");   
                }
                    return View("ProfesorPages");   
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you're trying to do here. Your form doesn't have any input element except the submit button. Of course you're not seeing anything posted back.

```
@model IEnumerable<Subject>

<form>
    ...
    <tbody>
        @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Model[i].ID" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" asp-for="Model[i].Name" />
                </td>
                ...
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    ...
</form>
```

Why??

- Why did you convert your IEnumerable to a list named item? Why not just enumerate your subjects directly?
- Why not create a different set of models called ViewModel and pass that to the View, instead of using your model from your database directly on the View?

Comment: I am not using my model from database. I call my web api and load list of all subjects and also i have a partial view where teacher can add new subject. When add all new subjects I call web api and save all new subjects. I change @model  in razor to be IList, and add input types as you suggest me and now it's works!

Comment: `IEnumerable` should work fine. Also maybe I was mistaken but the `Subject` seems like the model from the database. Anyway glad that worked out for you :)